# Activity from TabHost pops up when OnNewIntent NFC is called

Tags: java, android, android-tabhost, nfc

I've got NFC application with TabHost. 3 tabs are represented by 3 different activities. Each of these activities connect with NFC device. Below TabHost there is a common log window, which should always be seen.

For example, in FirstActivity we have:

```
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {

    action = intent.getAction();
    tagFromIntent = intent.getParcelableExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG);
    connection = true;

}
```

Problem is that onNewIntent (when phone dicsovers NFC tag) FirstActivity pops up to the top - so that we can't see common log window anymore. To use nfc tag, we have to near the nfc device again.

It's quite bothersome problem, has anyone idea how to solve this? 
Thank you.

Comment: Just use fragments...

Comment: Fragments? Can you be more specific?

Comment: See http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html for an example.

Comment: Thank you, now I got it. I didn't even realise that sth like this exists :)